# How to make animation in Android Studio button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

How can i make animation inside button on Android Studio like this;

[lookatthebutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKdkd.jpg)

[lookatthebutton2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSLUG.jpg)

Thanks so much;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is custom animation but you can use Gif image instead of animation.